# Batch remove empty directories (Removing as many directories as possible, but no files)

Tags: windows, batch

I'm running a batch script that clears files, in which I need to delete all empty folders. It is identical to the question posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24134/remove-empty-directory-trees-removing-as-many-directories-as-possible-but-no-fi

except I am using batch instead of bash (Windows 10).

I tried using `rmdir` but it would either remove dirs. and files or remove nothing.

Comment: Right but if any of the folders has a file in it it does not delete any folders, including empty ones

Comment: If you don't mind making a copy first, robocoy can copy subfolders that are not empty and skip those that are empty. Once the copy is done, the old folder can be removed, then the new copy can be renamed back.

Comment: Interesting Workaround. What command would I use?